# How does ProcessBuilder avoid OS command injection?

Tags: java, injection

while I understand that OS command injection needs to have the untrusted input to be validated, I see that people have been suggesting to use `ProcessBuilder(...).start()` over `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(..)`; is this because ProcessBuilder does not take command to be executed as a single string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overcame this vulnerability by using ESAPI's executeSystemCommand method which internally seems to be using ProcessorBuilder after validating the input though.